# Interface DHT22 to FPGA - elbert v2

Tags: vhdl, fpga, sensors, temperature

Now i make a circuit to measure temperature and humidity, then display on LCD. This is my code for DHT22, i use Elbert V2. 
After genarating my project, it did not go right.

I tested and my program did not to come to "end_sl"( last state). And i dont know why?. Any suggestions for me? thank you.

my code

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
entity DHT11 is
generic (
CLK_PERIOD_NS : positive := 83;    -- 12MHz
N: positive:= 40);
port(
    clk,rst : in std_logic ;
    singer_bus: inout std_logic; 
    dataout: out std_logic_vector (N-1 downto 0);
    tick_done: out std_logic
); 
end DHT11;
architecture Behavioral of DHT11 is

constant DELAY_1_MS: positive := 1*10**6/CLK_PERIOD_NS+1;
constant DELAY_40_US: positive := 40*10**3/CLK_PERIOD_NS+1;
constant DELAY_80_US: positive := 80*10**3/CLK_PERIOD_NS+1;
constant DELAY_50_US: positive := 50*10**3/CLK_PERIOD_NS+1; -- 
constant TIME_70_US: positive := 80*10**3/CLK_PERIOD_NS+1; --bit  > 70 us 
constant TIME_28_uS: positive := 30*10**3/CLK_PERIOD_NS+1; -- bit 0 > 28 us 
constant MAX_DELAY  : positive := 5*10**6/CLK_PERIOD_NS+1; -- 5 ms
type state_type is (reset,start_m,wait_res_sl,response_sl,delay_sl,start_sl,consider_logic,end_sl);
signal  index, next_index : natural range 0 to MAX_DELAY; 
signal  state, next_state : state_type; 
signal  data_out,next_data_out: std_logic_vector (N-1 downto 0);
signal  bit_in, next_bit_in: std_logic; 
signal  number_bit,next_number_bit: natural range 0 to 40; 
signal  oe: std_logic;  -- help to set input and output port.
begin   
--register
regis_state:process (clk,rst) begin
    if rst = '1' then 
        state <= reset; 
        index <= MAX_DELAY; 
        number_bit <= 0;
        bit_in <= '1';
        data_out <= (others => '0');
    elsif rising_edge(clk) then
        state <= next_state; 
        index <= next_index;
        number_bit <= next_number_bit;
        bit_in     <= next_bit_in;
        data_out   <= next_data_out;
    end if; 
end process regis_state; 
proces_state: process (singer_bus,index,state,bit_in,number_bit,data_out) begin 
    tick_done <= '0';
    next_data_out <= data_out;
    next_number_bit <= number_bit;
    next_state <= state;
    next_data_out <= data_out;
    next_index <= index;
    dataout <= (others => '0');
    oe <= '0';
    next_bit_in <= bit_in;
    case(state) is
        when reset =>   -- initial  
            if index = 0 then 
                next_state <= start_m; 
                next_index <= DELAY_1_MS;
                next_number_bit <= N-1;
            else
                next_state <= reset;
                next_index <= index - 1;                    
            end if;     
        when start_m =>  -- master send '1' in 1ms
            if index = 0 then 
                next_state <= wait_res_sl;
                next_index <= DELAY_40_US;
            else 
                oe <= '1'; 
                next_state <= start_m; 
                next_index <= index -1;
            end if ;
        when wait_res_sl => -- wait for slave response in 40us  --
            next_bit_in <= singer_bus;
            if  bit_in ='1' and next_bit_in = '0' then  -- 
                next_state <= response_sl;
            else 
                next_state <= wait_res_sl;  
            end if; 
        when response_sl => -- slave response in 80us 
            next_bit_in <= singer_bus;
            if bit_in ='0' and next_bit_in = '1' then 
                next_state <= delay_sl;
            else 
                next_state <= response_sl;
            end if;
        when delay_sl => -- wait for slave delay in 80us 
            if bit_in = '1' and next_bit_in ='0' then 
                next_state <= start_sl;
            else 
                next_state <= delay_sl;
            end if;
        when start_sl => -- start to prepare in 50us                
            if (bit_in = '0') and (next_bit_in = '1') then
                next_state <= consider_logic;
                next_index <= 0;
            elsif number_bit = 0 then 
                    next_state <= end_sl;
                    next_index <= DELAY_50_US;
                else 
                    next_state <= start_sl;
            end if;
        when consider_logic => -- determine 1 bit-data of slave 
            next_index <= index + 1;
            next_bit_in <= singer_bus;
            if bit_in = '1' and next_bit_in = '0' then -- the end of logic state
                next_number_bit <= number_bit -1;
                if (index < TIME_28_uS) then -- time ~ 28 us - logic = '0'
                    next_data_out <= data_out(N-2 downto 0) & '0';
                elsif (index < TIME_70_US) then -- time ~70 us - logic ='1' 
                    next_data_out <= data_out(N-2 downto 0) & '1'; 
                end if;
                    next_state <= start_sl; 
                    next_index <= DELAY_50_US;  
            elsif bit_in ='1' and next_bit_in ='1' then 
                next_state <= consider_logic;
            end if;
        when end_sl => -- tick_done = '1' then dataout has full 40 bit. 
            if index = 0 then 
                next_index <= MAX_DELAY; 
                next_state <= reset;    
            else 
                tick_done <= '1';
                dataout <= data_out;
                next_index <= index -1; 
                next_state <= end_sl;   
            end if;
    end case;
end process proces_state; 
--tristate IOBUFFER
singer_bus <= '0' when oe ='1' else 'Z';
end Behavioral;
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please share your test bench.

Comment: Oke, this is my test bench
https://drive.google.com/file/d/13ivHG0SOKJRU4Yuzo0oFBpKA-nVQIMsZ/view

Comment: I meant *in your question*. Just like the other code.

Comment: Wow, I just looked at the test bench. Please **do not** put that in your question. Let me see if I can find the time to show you how to write something like that more efficiently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many errors in your code. How did you debug exactly? Because it seems like you did not.

Why wait for 60 ms after the reset? you waste (valuable) simulation time. 6 ms is more then enough.

Looking at the simulation output, you can see the `state` does not advance *at all*: it's stuck ini `wait_res_sl`. The problem is that you have not added all the signals read in the process to the sensitivity list. I.e.

```
bit_in ='1' and next_bit_in = '0'
```

Will not detect a change if `next_bit_in` is not in the sensitivity list.

A problem -a common mistake made- is that your 'test bench' only provides input stimuli.... But it does not actually test anything.

And then the counters. Why is the delay counter called `index`? It doesn't index anything.

Why do your time delays not match their label? 70us -> 80 us. 28us -> 30 us.

Small thing don't call a RTL architecture `behavioral`

I tried to clean your code, seems to work now.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity dht2 is
    generic (
        clk_period_ns : positive := 83;    -- 12mhz
        data_width: positive:= 40);
    port(
        clk,rst : in std_logic ;
        singer_bus: inout std_logic; 
        dataout: out std_logic_vector(data_width-1 downto 0);
        tick_done: out std_logic
        ); 
end entity;

architecture rtl of dht2 is
    constant delay_1_ms: positive := 1*10**6/clk_period_ns+1;
    constant delay_40_us: positive := 40*10**3/clk_period_ns+1;
    constant delay_80_us: positive := 80*10**3/clk_period_ns+1;
    constant delay_50_us: positive := 50*10**3/clk_period_ns+1; -- 
    constant time_70_us: positive := 70*10**3/clk_period_ns+1; --bit  > 70 us 
    constant time_28_us: positive := 28*10**3/clk_period_ns+1; -- bit 0 > 28 us 
    constant max_delay  : positive := 5*10**6/clk_period_ns+1; -- 5 ms

    signal input_sync : std_logic_vector(0 to 2); 

    type state_type is (reset,start_m,wait_res_sl,response_sl,delay_sl,start_sl,consider_logic,end_sl);
    signal state : state_type; 
    signal delay_counter : natural range 0 to max_delay; 
    signal data_out : std_logic_vector (data_width-1 downto 0);
    signal bus_rising_edge, bus_falling_edge : boolean;
    signal number_bit : natural range 0 to data_width; 
    signal oe: std_logic;  -- help to set input and output port.
begin
    input_syncronizer : process(clk) begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            input_sync <= to_x01(singer_bus)&input_sync(0 to 1);
        end if;
    end process;

    bus_rising_edge <= input_sync(1 to 2) = "10";
    bus_falling_edge <= input_sync(1 to 2) = "01";

    --register
    regis_state:process (clk) begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            case(state) is
                when reset =>   -- initial
                    if delay_counter = 0 then 
                        number_bit <= data_width;
                        oe <= '1'; 
                        delay_counter <= delay_1_ms;
                        state <= start_m; 
                    else
                        delay_counter <= delay_counter - 1;                    
                    end if;     
                when start_m =>  -- master send '1' in 1ms
                    if delay_counter = 0 then 
                        oe <= '0'; 
                        delay_counter <= delay_40_us;
                        state <= wait_res_sl;
                    else 
                        delay_counter <= delay_counter -1;
                    end if ;
                when wait_res_sl => -- wait for slave response in 40us  --
                    if bus_falling_edge then  -- 
                        state <= response_sl;
                    end if; 
                when response_sl => -- slave response in 80us 
                    if bus_rising_edge then 
                        state <= delay_sl;
                    end if;
                when delay_sl => -- wait for slave delay in 80us 
                    if bus_falling_edge then 
                        state <= start_sl;
                    end if;
                when start_sl => -- start to prepare in 50us                
                    if bus_rising_edge then
                        delay_counter <= 0;
                        state <= consider_logic;
                    elsif number_bit = 0 then 
                        delay_counter <= delay_50_us;
                        state <= end_sl;
                    end if;
                when consider_logic => -- determine 1 bit-data of slave 
                    if bus_falling_edge then -- the end of logic state
                        number_bit <= number_bit - 1;
                        if (delay_counter < time_28_us) then -- time ~ 28 us - logic = '0'
                            data_out <= data_out(data_width-2 downto 0) & '0';
                        elsif (delay_counter < time_70_us) then -- time ~70 us - logic ='1' 
                            data_out <= data_out(data_width-2 downto 0) & '1'; 
                        end if;
                        delay_counter <= delay_50_us;  
                        state <= start_sl; 
                    end if;
                    delay_counter <= delay_counter + 1;
                when end_sl => -- tick_done = '1' then dataout has full 40 bit. 
                    if delay_counter = 0 then 
                        delay_counter <= max_delay; 
                        state <= reset;    
                    else 
                        tick_done <= '1';
                        dataout <= data_out;
                        delay_counter <= delay_counter - 1; 
                    end if;
            end case;
            if rst = '1' then 
                number_bit <= 0;
                data_out <= (others => '0');
                delay_counter <= max_delay; 
                state <= reset; 
            end if;
        end if; 
    end process regis_state; 
    --tristate iobuffer
    singer_bus <= '0' when oe ='1' else 'Z';
end architecture;
```

And test bench: I added one check, but you should make more checks: every time you do something, it should have an effect. You should test if that effect actually happens.

```
entity dht2_tb is end dht2_tb;

library ieee;
architecture behavior of dht2_tb is 
    use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
    --inputs
    signal clk : std_logic := '0';
    signal rst : std_logic := '0';
    --bidirs
    signal singer_bus : std_logic := 'H';
    --outputs
    signal tick_done : std_logic;
    -- clock period definitions
    constant clk_period : time := 83.33 ns;    -- 12mhz

    use ieee.math_real.all;
    -- This function generates a 'slv_length'-bit std_logic_vector with
    --  random values.
    function random_slv(slv_length : positive) return std_logic_vector is
        variable output : std_logic_vector(slv_length-1 downto 0);
        variable seed1, seed2 : positive := 65; -- required for the uniform function
        variable rand : real;
        -- Assume mantissa of 23, according to IEEE-754:
        --  as UNIFORM returns a 32-bit floating point value between 0 and 1
        --  only 23 bits will be random: the rest has no value to us.
        constant rand_bits : positive := 23;
        -- for simplicity, calculate remaining number of bits here
        constant end_bits : natural := slv_length rem rand_bits;
        use ieee.numeric_std.all;
    begin
        -- fill sets of 23-bit of the output with the random values.
        for i in 0 to slv_length/rand_bits-1 loop
            uniform(seed1, seed2, rand); -- create random float
            -- convert float to int and fill output
            output((i+1)*rand_bits-1 downto i*rand_bits) :=
                std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(integer(rand*(2.0**rand_bits)), rand_bits));
        end loop;
        -- fill final bits (< 23, so above loop will not work.
        uniform(seed1, seed2, rand);
        if end_bits /= 0 then
            output(slv_length-1 downto slv_length-end_bits) :=
                std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(integer(rand*(2.0**end_bits)), end_bits));
        end if;
        return output;
    end function;

    -- input + output definitions
    constant test_data_length : positive := 32;
    constant test_data : std_logic_vector(test_data_length-1 downto 0) := random_slv(test_data_length);
    signal data_out : std_logic_vector(test_data_length-1 downto 0);
begin
    -- instantiate the unit under test (uut)
    uut: entity work.dht2 -- use entity instantiation: no component declaration needed
        generic map (
            clk_period_ns => clk_period / 1 ns,
            data_width => test_data_length)
        port map (
            clk => clk,
            rst => rst,
            singer_bus => singer_bus,
            dataout => data_out,
            tick_done => tick_done
            );

    -- clock stimuli
    clk_process: process begin
        clk <= '0', '1' after clk_period/2;
        wait for clk_period;
    end process;

    -- reset stimuli
    rst_proc : process begin
        rst <= '1', '0' after 100 us;
        wait;
    end process;

    -- bidir bus pull-up
    -- as you drive the bus from the uut and this test bench, it is a bidir
    -- you need to simulate a pull-up ('H' = weak '1'). slv will resolve this.
    singer_bus <= 'H';

    -- stimulus process
    bus_proc: process
        -- we use procedures for stimuli. Increases maintainability of test bench

        -- procedure bus_init initializes the slave device. (copied this from your code)
        procedure bus_init is begin
    --      singer_bus <= 'Z'; -- initial 
            wait for 6 ms;  
            -- singer_bus <= '0'; -- master send 
            -- wait for 1 ms;
            singer_bus <= 'Z'; -- wait response for slave 
            wait for 40 us; 
            singer_bus <= '0'; -- slave pull low  
            wait for 80 us; 
            singer_bus <= 'Z'; -- slave pull up
            wait for 80 us; 
        end procedure;

        function to_string(input : std_logic_vector) return string is
            variable output : string(1 to input'length);
            variable j : positive := 1;
        begin
            for i in input'range loop
                output(j) := std_logic'image(input(i))(2);
                j := j + 1;
            end loop;
            return output;
        end function;

        -- procedure send_data 
        procedure send_data(data : std_logic_vector) is begin
            -- we can now send a vector of data,length detected automatically
            for i in data'range loop
                singer_bus <= '0';  -- slave start data transmission 
                wait for 50 us;
                singer_bus <= 'Z';  -- slave send bit;
                -- I found the only difference between sending bit '0'
                --  and '1' is the length of the delay after a '0' was send.
                case data(i) is
                    when '0' => wait for 24 us; 
                    when '1' => wait for 68 us;
                    when others =>
                        report "metavalues not supported for bus_proc send_data"
                            severity failure;
                end case;
                singer_bus <= '0';
            end loop;
            -- next is VHDL-2008 (else use ieee.std_logic_textio.all;)
            report "transmitted: "&to_string(data);
        end procedure;
    begin       
        wait until rst = '0';
        bus_init; -- call procedure

        send_data(test_data); -- call procedure

        wait for 100 us; -- final delay
        singer_bus <= 'Z'; -- release bus

        report "received: "&to_string(data_out);
        -- test correctness of output
        assert data_out = test_data
            report "data output does not match send data"
            severity error;

        report "end of simulation" severity failure;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

Comment: Thank u so much. I am seeing your code.I am a newbie and just begin with FPGA_Prototyping_by_VHDL_Examples book. Can you suggest for books or websites suit for me ?

Comment: 70us -> 80 us. 28us -> 30 us, they dont match as the label because in DHT22 datasheet, they are 70 us, 28 us but i afraid they will have some errors about times. So i do that.

Comment: @ThanhniênYênBái I fixed your code (had some time). The count was wrong: you needed to read an additional character. Check my updated code.

Comment: I understand the first code file you write, but i can not understand your test bench. Can you give something basic documents to its ? And this erorr: Line 103: <to_string> is not declared, how should i fix this.

Comment: @ThanhniênYênBái like I say in the text: set you simulator to VHDL-2008 mode. Although that VHDL standard is already 10 years old, many simulators still use the 1993 definition. I will add comments

Comment: Oh, i using ISE 14.7, it seems not support VHDL 2008. This 's right ?

Comment: @ThanhniênYênBái ok, I rewrote it to 1993 style. Xilinx sucks for not supporting VHDL-2008 in a tool they last updated february 2018...

Comment: @JHBonarious you 're so nice :))

Comment: @ThanhniênYênBái you're welcome. Actually I'm not supposed to fixe your problem for you: I'm supposed to give you hints on how to fix it yourself, so you learn how. But I wanted some finger-excersize, so I fixed it after all (although I don't know if it will work for you). I hope you can understand my code well enough to learn something from it.